# How to disable plugins in eclipse 3.6 Helios?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, helios

I have eclipse 3.6, i have installed lot of plugins. 
But i want to disable some of the plugins but dont know how :(
( I don't want to uninstall them as i may need them in some time future when i work on other projects)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In preferences, General, Startup and Shutdown. A lot of plugins will appear there with checkboxes. With luck, the one you're hoping to disable appears there.

If your plugin doesn't appear there, then you either have to uninstall it, hope it provides an option to disable itself, or live with it.

Comment: Ya worked for me. But are those the only ones would load during startup? or can other plugins still load them selfs without being listed there?

Comment: These are only the plugins that are 'kind' enough to allow themselves to be easily disabled. I guess the other plugins assume if you've installed it, you always want it to be there...

Comment: You can remove them by going to the plugins folder in the installation directory and move unwanted ones to a separate directory. If anything breaks restore them. Source: http://blog.sarathonline.com/2012/05/eclipse-indigo-without-mylyn.html

Comment: When I used this solution on the plugin "Toad Extension" it broke my workspace. It tried to build my workspace without ever finishing. This solution only seems to work with the right plugins!

Answer (score 23):

You can uninstall them all by the next procedure:

Help > About Eclipse SDK > Installation Details > Installed Software Tab > Select a plug-in you want to Uninstall > Click Uninstall button at the bottom

Comment: ... If the Uninstall button happens to be highlighted for the plugin to uninstall

Answer (score 4):

you can use the Plug-in Registry view offered by the pde.

here you can see the plug-ins installed, the active ones and, by actrivating the advanced operations, you can disable the various plugins

Comment: It works. But it's a risky way. Need more knowledge to know which should be disabled.

Comment: Cool. At least i have a way to disable.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the folder where your eclipse in the computer. Go the plugins folder. And delete the plugins. And restart eclipse again

Comment: That might not be a good idea since you might delete some of the plugins that come packaged with eclipse. In any case, if you still want to go that path, you should watch the eclipse log (after restarting eclipse) to see if there's any negative impact of your actions.