# Disabling EGit in Eclipse-CDT Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, egit

This thread: [How to disable EGit temporarily?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103048/how-to-disable-egit-temporarily) discusses how to disable EGit in Eclipse, but when I go to  `"Startup and Shutdown"`, there is no option to disable EGit.

How can I control what plug-ins are loaded in [Eclipse-CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/)?

Comment: Do you mean eclipse-CDT?

Comment: Thanks @bobestm. Yes, `Eclipse-CDT`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To uninstall plug-ins or software from Eclipse:

1. Help menu
2. Install New Software
3. In the dialog, select the little link that says "What is Already Installed"
4. Anything under the 'Installed Software' tab can be removed

I think in the latest release of Eclipse, you will NOT find eGit in this list. Instead you will find it under the features/plugins list. SO, it is not easy to remove. I would suspect you can still goto the Eclipse install directory and cherry pick it out but whats the point? Just follow bobestm advice and disconnect the project from git and CDT should not bother you about it (mine does not...)

You will not find eGit in the Startup/Shutdown preference anymore. I think what has happened is a much tighter integration of git into the IDE (and not with the CDT). This is a good thing, but I am not sure why you need it disabled.

Comment: Not everyone who uses Git, uses Eclipse/Git integration, it's sad that it seems to be forced on you in Eclipse at this point.  I found the answer by @bobestm to be satisfactory for now

Comment: I cannot see red-corss error anymore. How can I disable temperary?

Comment: How can it be removed in Juno? I don't see any option to remove installed software.

Comment: I can't stand comments like: "This is a good thing, but I am not sure why you need it disabled". People have different needs, preferences, choices. There are an infinite number of ways tools can be utilized and manipulated based on development needs. Just because someone doesn't do things the way YOU learned to do it does not make them ignorant.

Answer (score 55):

Ok, here's a suggestion.  You can disconnect the particular project from Egit by doing the following:
Right click on project->Team->Disconnect.

When you do wish hookup to the repo again, do right-click on project->Team->Share Project...

If you wish to disable the plugin itself, you would have to uninstall it.

Comment: How can I uninstall the EGit plugin as a whole? I tried looking around for an uninstall hook, but did not find any.

Comment: Since the plugin is crashing every single time, I'd really appreciate a way of really disabling it instead. It's just going to "connect" again (whatever that means) the next time I open it, and crash before I can disconnect.

Comment: I tried this too.. I can disconnect, but if I ever close the project and then open it at a later date, git is back on.

Comment: In Mars, disconnecting works great. it also does not reconnect again on restart. Uninstall in Mars is not possible. The uninstall button is grayed when you click on egit in the Already Installed Software section.

Answer (score 22):

The plugins are not easy to remove/disable in eclipse. But you can remove jar files of that plugins to remove a plugin.

In Linux or Mac, open the Terminal, and `cd` to eclipse folder.

```
mkdir disabled disabled/features disabled/plugins

mv features/*egit* disabled/features/
mv plugins/*jgit* disabled/plugins/
mv plugins/*egit* disabled/plugins
```

Read more in http://blog.sarathonline.com/2012/05/eclipse-indigo-without-mylyn.html

Comment: Thanks. Why would this not be a setting in Eclipse itself? It defies logic.